# Ruby: Remove multiple specific elements of an array from a condition

Tags: ruby, random, conditional-statements

New to Ruby, I write a random password generator with a "qwazerty" mode.

The program shall ask a desired password's length and whether the password shall or not include characters changing from azerty to qwerty keyboard layouts (the "qwazerty" type).
Once the password's parameters set, a password of the desired length and type is generated by pseudo-randomly picking among the array's characters.

The problem ? Whatever you answer when asked if you want a "qwazerty-sensitive" password, the qwazerty mode won't work. Most commented lines are remnants of previous failures I left if it could ever help.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

character_set = [ "!", "$", "%", "&", "'", "(", ")", "*", "+", ",", "-", ".", "/", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", ":", ";", "<", "=", ">", "?", "@", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "[", "]", "^", "_", "`", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "{", "|", "}", "~" ] # ASCII order, no 032, """, "\", "#".
bad_character_set = [ "!", "$", "%", "&", "'", "(", ")", "*", ",", "-", ".", "/", ":", ";", "?", "@", "A", "M", "Q", "W", "Z", "[", "]", "^", "`", "a", "m", "q", "w", "z", "{", "|", "}", "~" ]

puts """   ,----,    ,----,          ,---,      ,-,   ,----,,----,
  / // /    / // /,-,-,-,   / ,-'      / /   / // // // / 
 / /| |,-, / ,--'/ / / /-, / ',-,-,   / /-, / // // // /  
'-' '-''-''-'   '-----''-''----''-'  '-''-''----''----'   
R A N D O M   P A S S W O R D   G E N E R A T O R   1 . 0 0
\nEnter the password's length (in arabic numbers)."""
password_length = gets.to_i

puts "\nShall the password be qwazerty sensitive (\"yes\" or \"no\") ?"
password_type = gets #.match("/(|^)yes(|$)/i")

if password_type =~ /(|^)yes(|$)/i # == true
    character_set - bad_character_set
#   character_set.delete( "!", "$", "%", "&", "'", "(", ")", "*", ",", "-", ".", "/", ":", ";", "?", "@", "A", "M", "Q", "W", "Z", "[", "]", "^", "`", "a", "m", "q", "w", "z", "{", "|", "}", "~" )
#   character_set.delete_at( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13, 24, 25, 29, 30, 31, 43, 47, 53, 56, 57, 58, 59, 61, 62, 74, 78, 84, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91 )
else

end

password = Array.new

while password_length > 0 do
    password << character_set.sample
    password_length -= 1
end

puts "\n" + password.map(&:inspect).join('').to_s.gsub('"', '')
```

First, I tried to remove undesired characters from the character_set array.
Second, I tried to remove them one by one.
Third, I tried to subtract an array of the undesired characters to the character_set array.

… So far, nothing worked.

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand, what is your ultimate goal? I fear its a [XY Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @shivam Well I need my program to enable the qwazerty mode if I answer "yes" when prompted to answer it or anything else. This mode enabled, the character set the password generation is based on shall lose any and all character belonging to both qwerty and azerty keyboard layouts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is likely this line:

```
character_set - bad_character_set
```

[Array - Array](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-2D) returns a new array; it does not modify the recipient.

Try

```
character_set = character_set - bad_character_set
```

instead

Comment: Or even `character_set -= bad_character_set`

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell Oh, for Christ's sake. I didn't even see it. Thanks, you two.